# Python variable string concatenation

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I am trying to iterate through a loop (selecting verts) in maya python, but am botching the syntax of concatenating the variable (sel) correctly in the loop...

```
sel = mc.ls(sl=True)
for num in range(0,noOfVerts, 2):
    mc.select("sel.vtx[%d]" % num, add = True)
```

Is using the variable as a string instead of the object itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this quotes and use directly your variable for the first parameter instead of the string representing the variable name:

```
sel = mc.ls(sl=True)
for num in range(0,noOfVerts, 2):
    mc.select(sel.vtx[num], add=True)
```

Comment: `mc.ls` returns a `list`, which has no `vtx` method

Answer (score 0):

Because you are telling it to treat it as a string.  I suspect you want something like:

```
mc.select(sel.vtx[num], add = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assemble the string from the variable, rather than just use the literal `sel`

```
sel = mc.ls(sl=True)
for num in range(0,noOfVerts, 2):
    mc.select("%s.vtx[%d]" % (sel[0], num), add = True)
```

This assumes you only have one object selected. Otherwise you simply need to loop over `sel` as well

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do the loop but you would end up putting MANY things in the undo stack. This would get ridiculosly slow if you had many vertices. **Try to avoid this**. Maya does offer a wildcard selector so you can simply do:

```
for item in mc.ls(sl=True):
   mc.select("%s.vtx[*]" % item, add=True)
```

Instead of selecting them one at a time that is hideously slow. The alternative is to generate a lots of names and select them in one go. So don't call many selects when one select will do. This lowers your memory consumption and makes it faster (yes this is significant if you have a 1000 or more vertices).

On the other note you could also sidestep the entire code with:

```
mc.select(mc.polyListComponentConversion(toVertex=True))
```

Ps: maya also knows slice operations for component selection just like python. So its possible to select obj.vtx[0:100]

Comment: As you may have noticed general python skill may not translate well into how you'd use Maya efficiently.